# Pandas, Numpy, coalesce multiple columns and eliminate null values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've this Dataframe

```
df_stack = pd.DataFrame([['age', 0.0417084448844436],
 ['age', 0.0417084448844436],
 ['sex', 0.0506801187398187],
 ['sex', 0.0506801187398187],
 ['bp', 0.1506801187],
 ['bp', 0.1506801187]])
```

I need to get this result

```
     age         bp       sex
0   0.041708    0.15068   0.05068   
1   0.041708    0.15068   0.05068
```

In SQL we can use a "coalesce" function, that eliminate the null values and pull up the values.
Do we have something similar with Pandas?
Thank you in advance

Comment: we have [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html): `df_stack.assign(k=df_stack.groupby(0).cumcount()).pivot('k',0,1)` , or `df_stack.set_index([df_stack.groupby(0).cumcount(),0])[1].unstack()` : you can check Q10 on the linked Q&A

Comment: Yes i did Check, it's not same issue. besides none of the solutions you provide in your comments works. Returns error messages.

Comment: well something like "WTF" is not used here in SO (comment now removed) where we respect everyone. Anyway if you can edit your question with what you have tried thus far (including ,my comments), I can retract the close vote. Until then it looks like a pivot to me, also `df_stack` is just a list of list as you have shown in your question?

Comment: Absolutely. df_stack is just a list of list as you have shown in your question?,no it's a dataframe, Ok that one is on me, but I specifically say, a DataFrame. "I've this Dataframe". Anyway I've rearrange the code. it's a Dataframe not a List. Now, I need to get rid of all null values and push remaining values at same level. And that's not in Q10

Comment: I assumed so anyways, if I run your code for `df_stack` and then run `df_stack.set_index([df_stack.groupby(0).cumcount(),0])[1].unstack()` , I get the result what you were looking for.. even the code with `pivot` works for me. so technically it is still a duplicate , also you dont have null values in the example `df_stack` , you may want to edit the example to be clearer

Comment: Can you share your results please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221822/discussion-between-anky-and-carlos-carvalho).